# AngularJS karma jasmine test can't find route provider

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I have angular script post.js and test for it post_test.js.

my `post.js` file

```
var Post = angular.module('Post', []);

Post
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/post', {
                controller: 'PostCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'src/posts/partials/post.html'
            })
        ;
    }]);
```

and my `post_test.js` file:

```
'use strict';

describe('Post module', function() {

    beforeEach(module('Post'));

    describe('Post controller', function(){

        it('should ....', inject(function($controller) {
            //spec body
            var PostCtrl = $controller('PostCtrl');
            expect(PostCtrl).toBeDefined();
        }));

    });
});
```

in `karma.conf.js` I load

```
files: [
    'app/components/angular/angular.js',
    'app/components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
    'app/components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    'app/app.js',
    'app/src/**/*.js' // post.js, post_test.js
],
```

Everything seems OK, but angular returns this error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module Post due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider
```

I don't know why. I load `angular-route.js` before `post.js`. I've checked and it loads correctly. I've put `alert(1)` before defining `$routeProvier` and I've seen it in console. So this file is loading correctly, but in next file - test file it still doesn't work.

Comment: You can also do `beforeEach(module('Post', 'ngRoute'))` instead. But since Post actually depends on ngRoute, the posted answer would make more sense. It is ok to load a dependency (ngRoute) explicitly in every module that depends on it, exactly to avoid situations like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngRoute` module should be loaded as well.

Replace:

```
var Post = angular.module('Post', []);
```

with:

```
var Post = angular.module('Post', ['ngRoute']);
```

Comment: But it works normally - when I use this in my angular application as an user. And it's loaded in `app.js`. Script in `app.js` loads ngRoute and also Post module. Maybe should I load in different way this scripts in `karma.conf.js`?

Comment: I guess because the module declared in *app.js* loads ngRoute, *before* loading Post module. But this is error-prone. As Post depends on ngRoute you should really declare the latter in the dependencies array of Post. Moreover, in `post_test.js`, only Post module is loaded before each test. ngRoute is not loaded because it is not a dependency of Post module.